# Remove filter callback: method in class

Tags: filters

I need to disable this filter:

```
$message = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_mail_content', $this->style_inline( $message ) );
```

The **style_inline()** function exist in a class called **WC_Email**.
So I tried:

```
remove_filter("woocommerce_mail_content", WC()->WC_Email->style_inline());
```

But it was a wild guess and it didn't work.

Link to the full apply_filters code: [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Email.html#465)

Link to the style_online() function: [here](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Email.html#396-419)

Comment: are you trying to remove the inline styles from the message?

Answer (score 1):

Note that to remove a *filter callback* from the `woocommerce_email_content` filter, you first need to have it registered via:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_content', ...some-custom-callback... );
```

but it looks like you're trying to remove the inline styles from the message.

I guess you need the text/html content type, so try instead to override the styles with (untested):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_styles', '__return_null' );
```

Comment: What if i need to have a condition check to remove `woocommerce_email_styles` hook?  Also i think it is not possible to have an `add_filter` inside function.

Comment: I guess it depends on how plugins are hooking into that filter. One could try to create a callback for the `woocommerce_email_styles` filter  with high priority (e.g. 9999) and include the check there if null should be returned?